# PostgreSQL group by all fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
table1.*,
sum(table2.amount) as totalamount
FROM table1
join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
GROUP BY table1.*;
```

I got the error:  column "table1.key" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.
Are there any way to group "all" field?

Answer (score 26):

There is no shortcut syntax for grouping by all columns, but it's probably not necessary in the described case. **If** the `key` column **is a primary key,** it's enough when you use it:

```
GROUP BY table1.key;
```

Comment: What do we do if we are grouping columns of a view and not a table?
IIUC there isn't any key column associated with a view. Is there?

Comment: @VikasPrasad - This depends on how the view is defined. If it simply contains only <table1> columns then the planner can recognize the primary key.

Comment: In my case, I am joining around 6 7 views with one main view. But all join will result in one to one result and thus I want the resultant view to identify the primary key from the underlying main view.

Comment: I'll note that grouping rarely includes a primary key on a single table or on the most granular table in a join since that would likely just return *all* rows .

Comment: The question concerns a typical one-to-many relationship. Of course, grouping columns of a single table by PK makes no sense (just like grouping by all columns).

Comment: @klin what about foreign table through foreign data wrapper in Postgres, it seems like it can't recognise the primary key of the underlying table.

Comment: @gogofan - unfortunately, a foreign server knows nothing about a primary key of the underlying table.

Answer (score 11):

You have to specify all the column names in `group by`  that are selected and are not part of aggregate function ( `SUM/COUNT` etc)

```
select c1,c2,c4,sum(c3) FROM  totalamount
group by c1,c2,c4;
```

A shortcut to avoid writing the columns again in `group by` would be to specify them as numbers.

```
select c1,c2,c4,sum(c3) FROM  t
group by 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 5):

I found another way to solve, not perfect but maybe it's useful:

```
SELECT string_agg(column_name::character varying, ',') as columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
AND table_name   = 'your_table
```

Then apply this select result to main query like this:

```
$columns = $result[0]["columns"];

SELECT
table1.*,
sum(table2.amount) as totalamount
FROM table1
join table2 on table1.key = table2.key
GROUP BY $columns;
```

Comment: That's informative to a non-postgresql person like myself: actually the usage of the `$result[0][columnName]` is new to me